# Perl function "waits" before returning 1 to main function

Tags: mysql, database, perl

I have a Perl script, that calls several functions which perform MySQL database tasks from the main function. However, the whole script was way too slow, and by printing log messages, I investigated that it looks like as if it were just "waiting" before giving the control back to the main function.

By looking at the MySQL's processlist, I saw a Sleep process with NULL Info just counting up - and until it is doing something, the Perl function won't return to main function, although the Perl script itself has performed its commands, and everything was done successfully.

**Example:**

```
use IO::Handle;
STDERR->autoflush(1);
STDOUT->autoflush(1);

sub SomeFunction{
   // writing into MySQL database
   print localtime()."log2";
   return 1;
}

print localtime()."log1";
&SomeFunction();
print localtime()."log3";
```

The delay is between `log2` and `log3`, and until this time, there is a Sleep process in the MySQL's processlist.

What cause this and how can I increase the performance of this script?

Comment: If those print statements get buffered, you can't really conclude anything from them. Print out exact times, not just messages, and turn on autoflush.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that of course I do use localtime() concatenated to the message, and the followings: 

`use IO::Handle;
STDERR->autoflush(1);
STDOUT->autoflush(1);`

Comment: Could you show a minimal working example that actually exhibits this behaviour? See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance. As your code currently is, it won't even compile (`_SomeFunction` vs `SomeFunction`, `"log2;` and `"log3;` miss a closing quote).

Comment: Sorry for the typos, unfortunately I don't have the code on me. I am interested in general that what can prevent a function returning the control back to the main?

Comment: Please show your DBI code, copied from your original program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl does not wait for anything on scope exit. But exiting a scope can cause arbitrary code to be executed. For example, exiting a scope can cause objects to become unreferenced and destroyed, which would involve calling their destructor. There are [other means](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scope%3a%3aOnExit) too.